# Setting localleader

Tags: vimrc, leader

I've tried setting localleader using:

```
:let localleader="]"
```

And it seems to be 'working':

```
:let localleader
localleader            ]
```

However, when I try and run a command using localleader, it doesn't seem to register, and is using the general leader. For example, after I do:

```
:autocmd FileType python nnoremap <localleader>c I#<esc>
```

Hitting `]c` does nothing...but hitting `\c` (normal leader) actually works. What's wrong here? Perhpaps I'm misunderstanding the use of `leader` vs `mapleader` ?

Comment: Leader keys need to be set before any mapping that uses them. Is it your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`:h <LocalLeader>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3cLocalLeader%3e)

> `<LocalLeader>` is just like `<Leader>`, except that it uses `"maplocalleader"` instead of `"mapleader"`.

So you need

```
let maplocalleader="]"
```